# Cannot update Windows 10, get winload.efi error 0xc0000225

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, windows-update, uefi

Can anyone tell me how to update my Windows 10 64-bit computer to the latest build?  I would prefer an option that only uses official Microsoft tools and does not involve deleting all my files, but I'd like to hear about other options too.

Currently, the `winver` command reports that I have "Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.753)".

On numerous occasions, I used the "Update and Shutdown" and "Update and Restart" options that appear when I type Ctrl+Alt+Delete and open the power menu in the lower right.  When I use one of those options, I always get the following blue "Recovery" screen the next time the computer boots:
[image: The whole screen is blue and it says: Recovery. Your PC/Device needs to be repaired. This application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors. File: \windows\system32\winload.efi. Error code: 0xc0000225. You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer]

I have tried various options on that screen and they did not do anything useful.  I usually just press Ctrl+Alt+Delete when I see this screen and then the computer succeeds in booting Windows again but the version number is not updated.

It's crazy how many ways there are to update Windows, but I did try four other ways.

1. I pressed Windows+I to open the Settings app and used the "Update and Security" interface there.  Sometimes it tells me it has a feature update (I think it might have said build 1607 or something like that).  Sometimes (like now) it says my device is up to date.  So it seems to be malfunctioning.
2. I tried Microsoft's [Windows 10 Update Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159635/windows-10-update-assistant) (Windows10Upgrade9252.exe).  This app seems to be better than the first one because it consistently says "This PC is running version 10586.  The latest version is 14393."  I tried using it, but I think I still got the same blue Recovery screen after rebooting and the build number never changed.
3. I tried Microsoft's [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) (MediaCreationTool.exe).  It has an option to update the PC it is running on, but when it reboots, I still get the same blue Recovery screen.  When I boot to Windows again, it shows me the error code "0xC1900101 - 0x20017" and says "The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during BOOT operation."  Here is the [setuperr.log file](https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/0001864578eb0e6d89c7169ca89bd373) that I got from this process.  The Media Creation Tool also has an option to create an ISO for installing Windows, so I tried that.  When I ran "setup.exe" from the ISO, but I ultimately got the same error.
4. I tried making a recovery USB disk thing using some facility in Windows but I did not see an option for reinstalling Windows without losing my files.

In case it matters, the computer is an [ASUS G752VL-DH71](http://store.asus.com/us/item/201509AM220002986) laptop and I added a [SAMSUNG 950 PRO M.2 512GB PCI-Express 3.0 x4 SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820147467) to it.  I then installed Windows on the SSD and deleted all the original partitions on the spinning platter hard drive.  The SSD is C: and the spinning platter is D:.  I also added 2x16 GB of RAM to the computer, for a total of 48 GB.

Another issue with the computer is that it when it wakes up from sleeping, it never actually remembers what state it was in, and any programs I was running when I went to sleep have been terminated.  I am just saying this in case it makes it easier to figure out what is wrong with Windows Update; I don't expect people answering to know what is wrong with sleep mode.  **Update: Sleep is working properly now and I think the way I got it to work was by uninstalling the Samsung NVMe driver and letting Windows use its built-in NVMe driver instead.  There is probably a drive speed tradeoff.**

Please let me know if you want more details about my system or any of the things I tried.

Here is a previous questions I asked about installing Windows 10 on this same machine:

[Samsung PRO 950 SSD recognized as SATA instead of PCIe in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1082592/samsung-pro-950-ssd-recognized-as-sata-instead-of-pcie-inwindows-10)

My situation is different from a lot of other posts I have seen about error 0xc0000225 because for me, that error is just a temporary thing that goes away the next time I boot, and for me it is correlated with my attempts to update Windows to the latest build.

Comment: "I also added 2x16 GB of RAM to the computer, for a total of 48 GB."  How long ago did you add that extra RAM?  If you kick it back to the original RAM sticks that the machine came with, does it behave any differently? (I'm thinking maybe the RAM you added is faulty).

Comment: 0xC1900101 - 0x20017 = "A driver has caused an illegal operation.
Windows was not able to migrate the driver, resulting in a rollback of the operating system. 
This is a safeOS boot failure, typically caused by drivers or non-Microsoft disk encryption software. " make sure you don't use any 3rd party encryption tool

Comment: @magicandre1981: I'm not using third-party-encryption tools but I am using a third-party (Samsung) driver for the SSD that Windows is installed on.  Any idea how to figure out exactly what driver caused the error?  I updated my question to include a link to the setuperr.log file but it does not seem to name a driver.  I might try switching the BIOS back so that the Samsung driver is recognized as SATA instead of PCIe, but that is sort of a random guess.  Techie007:  Sure, I'll try that as one of my last resorts.  My RAM was installed around the same time I set up the computer, a year ago.

Comment: go to the standard NVMe driver that Windows 10 comes with and now try to upgrade to 1607 or wait 10 month to go directly to 1703 (Creators Update), which will replace 1607.

Comment: Do you know the Samsung driver is causing the problem?

Comment: no, because I don't use a NVMe based SSD. but try it.

Comment: have you tried this with the driver?

Comment: also, next month the version 1703 (creators update) gets released. try to update from 1511 to 1703 with the ISOs from 1703. this week MS decides which build gets the final 1703 version,

Comment: @magicandre1981: I uninstalled the Samsung driver and Windows reverted to using its own driver (stornvme.sys).  I still get the same blue screen error when I try to update.  I guess I'll wait for that update next month and see if it works.

Comment: hm, try the Creators Update 1703. If nothing helps, flatten the laptop and install Win10 Creators Update 1703 from scratch via ISO.

Comment: @DavidGrayson You are attempting to do the update, from a mounted 1607 ISO and not from Windows Update, right?

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for the comment.  No, I tried it in the four ways listed in my question (see "It's crazy how many ways there are to update Windows").  I'll try to figure out how to do the mounted ISO thing now that you mention it.

Comment: Its simple.  You download the current 1607 ISO, you mount the iSO, you run the setup.exe within Windows.

Comment: Should I use the media creation tool from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to make an ISO or should I be able to download an actual ISO from Microsoft?  (I could not find the latter.)

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did it that way with the ISO but I got the same results as I did when I tried to directly install using the Windows Media Creation Tool:  0xC1900101 - 0x20017 after booting.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Upgrading to 1607 via DVD didn't work for me, but I found a workaround: http://community.acer.com/t5/V-and-VN-Series-Laptops/does-the-VN7-592G-support-NVMe-booting/m-p/482680#M14761.

Comment: Also, 1703 throws the exact same error!

Comment: My Windows eventually died and I did clean install, so it will be hard for me to verify any answers.

Comment: Someone emailed me and said:  "he workaround described in https://www.dell.com/support/article/at/de/atbsdt1/sln301036/windows-10-install-with-nvme-ssd-and-sata-drives?lang=en worked with my mainboard: temporarily turning on CSM and using only the Legacy ROMs while still booting in UEFI mode."